# PHP Curl URL $Filter

Tags: php, api, curl, filter

Trying to filter a CURL request and I can't get it to do anything. Here is what I have.

```
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.adp.com/hr/v2/workers?$filter=workers/workAssignments/assignmentStatus/statusCode/codeValue%20eq%20%27A%27",
    CURLOPT_SSLCERT => $auth['cert'],
    CURLOPT_SSLKEY => $auth['key'],
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "gzip",
    CURLOPT_POST => "",
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $ADP_token,
    'Accept: application/json',
  ),
));
```

I know I have the correct information in the URL but this still returns all results. The URL works in POSTMAN.

Not sure if this helps but curl_getinfo() returns the URL missing the `$filter`:

```
[url] => https://api.adp.com/hr/v2/workers?=workers/workAssignments/assignmentStatus/statusCode/codeValue%20eq%20%27A%27
```

I also can't get a simple $top records to work which looks like below.
Original URL - https://api.adp.com/hr/v2/workers?$top=5

curl_get_info() below

```
[url] => https://api.adp.com/hr/v2/workers?=5
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure about that code? If you would dump the URL you are calling you would spot the error:

```
CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.adp.com/hr/v2/workers?$filter=workers/workAssignments/assignmentStatus/statusCode/codeValue%20eq%20%27A%27"
```

So, you are using the **variable** `$filter` in a double quoted string, which causes that **variable** to be replaced. What does `$filter` contain? Probably, it's even not defined?

If you want to continue using that exact URL, but not replace `$filter` by its content, you should use single quotes. This leaves the string exactly as it is, and does not replace the variable (which was not meant to be a variable)

Comment: $filter is what I have to use based on the API itself. It does work using POSTMAN. can get information here https://developers.adp.com/articles/api/workers-v2-api

Have also tried replacing $filter with %24filter

Comment: It's okay that calling that URL using another tool might help - but if you use **double quotes**, the `$filter` part is replaced with the content of that variable. If you have not defined that variable, `$filter` is replaced by simply nothing. Just dump the option array and you will see

Comment: The single quotes fixed the issue. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Changing

CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.adp.com/hr/v2/workers?$filter=workers/workAssignments/assignmentStatus/statusCode/codeValue%20eq%20%27A%27"

to

CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.adp.com/hr/v2/workers?$filter=workers/workAssignments/assignmentStatus/statusCode/codeValue%20eq%20%27A%27'

Comment: Can you explain that further? What have you changed? Why was that change neccessary?